# Php how to change background color <td> table?

Tags: php

I have a website and I prediction soccer. http://goaltips.nl/zeynel/Almanya2.php

I want to change background color(green) of the away wins fields if the nummer is bigger than 40 and Data is bigger than 5.

[image]

I have use this code for main page;

```
<?php

include 'almanya2fft.php';
include 'almanya2macsonu.php';
include 'almanya2ikibucuk.php';

foreach($array as $key => $data) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$IkiBucukAltPrediction[$key]." \r %".$IkiBucukUstPrediction[$key]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$VerisayisiData[$key]."</td>";
}
?>
</table>
</div>
```

and for almanya2ikibucuk.php is;

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $IkiBucukAlt=0;
    $IkiBucukUst=0;
    $Verisayisi=0;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Almanya2 where B = '{$val['B']}' AND E = '{$val['E']}' AND F = '{$val['F']}' AND O ='{$val['O']}' AND A = '*'  ";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // output data of each row 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($row['T'] == A){
               $IkiBucukAlt++;
            }else{
                $IkiBucukUst++;
            }
        }
        //We use an array rather than overriding everytime
    $VerisayisiData[$key]=$rowcount;
        $IkiBucukAltPrediction[$key] = round(($IkiBucukAlt/$rowcount )*100);
        $IkiBucukUstPrediction[$key] = round(($IkiBucukUst/$rowcount)*100);
    } else {
        echo " ";
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

What is the best way to do this conditions.
I hoop i was clear and someone can help me...
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after you started your foreach loop get the needed color :

```
$color = '';
if ($AwayPrediction[$key] > 40 && $VerisayisiData[$key] > 5) {
    $color = "style='background-color : green';"; 
}
```

Then add the style to each cell :

```
echo "<td ".$color.">".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
```

So when the condition is true, an inline css is applied and colors your cell else it does nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to ask you one more thing, l have in totally 18 leagues(18 separate php page), what about if I want to show in a one separate page 20 best of  all leagues (mix) $AwayPrediction[$key]. How can I do that ? Do you have any suggestions ? I don't know if I should make a new question ! Thank you.

Comment: You should make a new question which the answer is using a MySQL query ;)

Comment: Don't forget to close this post choosing the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ternary operator:

```
foreach($array as $key => $data) {
    $color = $AwayPrediction[$key] > 40 && $VerisayisiData[$key] > 5 ? 'style="background-color:green"' : ''; 
    echo "<tr $color>";
    echo "<td>".$data['H']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['M']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$AwayPrediction[$key]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$IkiBucukAltPrediction[$key]." \r %".$IkiBucukUstPrediction[$key]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$VerisayisiData[$key]."</td>";
}
```